# Best way to setup configuration for an npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

I am looking for a good way to setup configuration for an npm module I'm working on.

The module has two functions `notify.sms.send()` and `notify.email.send()`. I'm also providing a third abstract function that calls both (or whichever are enabled) called `notify.send()`.

I have an object called `notify.cfg` which is just a simple object hash `{}`.

I'm wondering if this is a good way to do this. Because its a module, I can't hardcode anything and configuration should be passed in when the module is required....like this:

```
//setup smtp server
var smtp = {
    host: xxx,
    user: user,
    pass: pass,
    port: port
};

//setup email headers
var email = {
    to: 'user@example.com',
    from: 'sender@example.com'
};

var notify = require('app-notify');

//set your configuration
notify.cfg.email = email;
notify.cfg.smtp = smtp;
```

The signature of `notify.cfg` is this:

```
var cfg = {};
exports.cfg = cfg;
```

I'm running into some issues while testing where when I overwrite the `notify.cfg = myConfig` in my `beforeEach` tests it seems to still retain older data from previous tests that have run. I don't know if its this config setup for my module or the way I'm writing my tests.

For anyone interested the code is here: https://github.com/chovy/app-notify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively making configuration singleton thus package becomes less usable. A typical API looks like:

```
var Notify = require('app-notify');
var notify = new Notify({
  email : ...
  smtp : ...
});
```

If a user wants a singleton `notify` object they can just `module.exports = new Notify({...})` and require it elsewhere.

Your `index.js` file would look like this:

```
function Notify(config) {
  if (!(this instanceof Notify))
    return new Notify(config);

  ....
}

module.exports = Notify;
```

`instanceof` check is used to make it possible to omit `new` keyword.

Comment: Can you give me the signature of what the ./index.js looks like with this method? I think this is more inline with what I need.